# spdlog logger construction - make_unique doesnt compile

Tags: c++

i want to have a spdlog logger in my class as a private member, which is even suggested in the documentation. First disappointment: no copy or move constructor for spdlog::logger. So if I want a more complex logger I have to jump through some hoops. let's ignore that and just use a unique_ptr.

I cant construct a unique pointer from a logger using make_unique. Doing it "manually" works fine though.

```
std::unique_ptr<spdlog::logger> logger;

//works!

spdlog::logger* tmp = new spdlog::logger("logger", {console_sink, file_sink});
logger.reset(tmp);

//does NOT compile! "no matching function call to make_unique" - why?
logger = std::make_unique<spdlog::logger>("logger", {console_sink, file_sink});
```

Why doesnt the make_unique call work?

Comment: Fixed the code formatting. (On this site, you shouldn't use `<pre>`, because it behaves badly with `<>` characters. Indent code by four spaces - and an easy way is to highlight code, then press the "`{}`" at the top of the editor box.)

Answer (score 1):

A function template cannot **deduce** an argument type for an initializer list (a *braced-init-list*), so you can’t use one with functions like `make_unique` that deduce *all* of their (variadic) arguments.  The compiler can’t look through the function to see the `spdlog::logger` constructors, but with a direct `new` it can *try* interpreting the initializer list in terms of (the appropriate parameter for) each constructor during overload resolution.

(It is possible to pass explicit template arguments to avoid the need for deduction, but that’s cumbersome at least and often forbidden (for the standard library).)

Answer (score 1):

`make_unique` is a function template, and can't deduce that you want a `spdlog::sinks_init_list` as the second constructor argument.

What will work is the following:
`std::make_unique<spdlog::logger>("logger", spdlog::sinks_init_list{console_sink, file_sink});` since you're specifying the type of the second argument.